# True or False: there is a space $X$ such that $S^1$ is homeomorphic to $X\times X$

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-topology

I had an exam this morning, one of the questions asked about the truth of the statement

> There is a space $X$ such that $S^1$ is homeomorphic to $X\times X$.

I said that this was false and this was my reasoning... was I correct? (Note, an earlier part of the question asked me to prove $\pi_1(Y\times Z)=\pi_1(Y)\times\pi_1(Z)$, I took this as a hint.)

Suppose for the sake of contradiction that such an $X$ exists. Then $\Bbb{Z}\cong G\times G$ where $G\cong\pi_1(X)$. Let $\Phi$ be the isomorphism.

Let $\Phi(1)=(g_1,g_2)\in G\times G$. Then at least one of $g_1,g_2$ is nonzero, since $\Phi(0)=(0,0)$ (the identity on $G\times G$, and $\Phi$ is injective). Without loss of generality $g_1\ne 0$. Then which element $n\in\Bbb{Z}$ has $\Phi(n)=(kg_1,0)$? Since $$kg_1=\underbrace{g_1+\dots +g_1}_k\in G,$$
and $\Phi$ is surjective, such an $n$ should exist. But this is not possible since $\Phi(n)=(kg_1,0)$ implies (since $\Phi$ is a homomorphism) that $kg_1=ng_1$ and $ng_2=0$, and since $k$ was arbitrary and this need not hold if $k\ne 0$.

Comment: In your context, do homeomorphism and isomorphism mean the same thing?

Comment: @Vincent They do not: the homeomorphism is between the topological spaces $S^1$ and $X\times X$ (a bijective, continuous map with continuous inverse); the isomorphism is between the groups $\pi_1(S^1)$ and $\pi_1(X)\times \pi_1(X)$ (a bijective group homomorphism)

Comment: You're close but I don't think this is completely correct. You're supposed to be *finding* an $n$, so you can just choose $n=k$ then $kg_1=ng_1$, and you could still have $ng_2=0$ without issue.

Comment: @AlexMathers yes you are right. Now I am trying to resurrect that proof. Maybe it is that $ng_2=0$ would imply $g_2=0$, since in general, $n=k$ may not be the identity. Then I seek an $m$ such that $\Phi(m)=(g_2,g_1)$. This would need in the first "coordinate" $mg_1=g_2=0$, implying $m=0$. But $\Phi(0)=(0,0)\ne (g_2,g_1)$ since $g_1\ne 0$.

Comment: You can also show that $X^2$ minus 2 points is connected (for $X$ uncountable and connected, say) and the circle minus 2 points is disconnected.

Comment: @HennoBrandsma Perhaps showing it directly wouldn't be difficult then -- connectedness and being uncountable are topological invariants?

Comment: @Szmagpie No, it's not that hard, I can write a proof as an alternative answer tomorrow, time permitting. It uses basic connectedness arguments. But the algebraic topology approach is also instructive. Both show ideas that are more widely applicable.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your idea is OK, using homotopy groups.

Suppose $\mathbb{Z} = G \times G$ for some (Abelian) group $G$, which must be infinite. Then note that $\{0\} \times G$ and $G \times \{0\}$ are infinite subgroups of $G \times G$ that intersect only in the unit element $\{(0,0)\}$. By the isomorphism that supposedly exists, such subgroups should also exist in the integers.

But any subgroup of $\mathbb{Z}$ is of the form $n\mathbb{Z}$ and any two of those have infinite intersection (at least $nm\mathbb{Z}$ for $n\mathbb{Z}$ and $m\mathbb{Z}$), so such subgroups cannot exist.

Using your original approach: suppose $h: \mathbb{Z} \rightarrow G \times G$ is an isomorphism, and $h(1) = (g_1,g_2)$, so that $h(n) = (ng_1, ng_2)$. As $(0,g_2)$ should be an image, $h(k) = (0,g_2)$ for some $k$, but it also equals $(kg_1, kg_2)$ so $kg_1 = 0$, and $kg_2 = g_2$, the latter implies $k=1$ (and then $g_1 = 0$ from the first equation), or $g_2 = 0$. In either case the image of $\mathbb{Z}$ can only be a subset of $G \times \{0\}$ or $\{0\} \times G$, both of which are never all of $G \times G$.